# Data binding the Image control in Windows 8 to a URL?

Tags: image, data-binding, windows-8, windows-8.1

In Windows 8/Store programming, how would you go about databinding an image to a URL. In other platforms I've worked with, I would set the source property (or equivalent) to the URL and the platform would handle it for me, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I'm currently binding it to a property for my business object that is of type "string", and returns the URL of the image that I want populated in the image control. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is really easy.

Code:

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

ImageUrl is a Uri containing the path to the remote image.